# How to define gl.DrawBuffers COLOR_ATTACHMENTi with golang bindings for openGL

Tags: opengl, go, framebuffer

Using "github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.5-core/gl" the golang bindings for setting the array of color_attachments is as follows:

```
// Specifies a list of color buffers to be drawn into
func DrawBuffers(n int32, bufs *uint32) {
    C.glowDrawBuffers(gpDrawBuffers, (C.GLsizei)(n), (*C.GLenum)(unsafe.Pointer(bufs)))
}
```

In c++ you would do this like:

```
// Set "renderedTexture" as our colour attachement #0
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);

// Set the list of draw buffers.
GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers); // "1" is the size of DrawBuffers
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how you are expected to pass an array of buffers to this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ya that's the c++ way but I was trying to understand how to do this but in GO. There are bindings that allow you to use openGL c++ in GO, but it was unclear how this one worked and the explanations/documentation provided is lacking. Kugels answer below is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a pointer to the first element: `gl.DrawBuffers(int32(len(attachments)), &attachments[0])`. I hope this answers your question.

Full example: https://github.com/Kugelschieber/go-game/blob/e88c16372587ddb958753bf70fde9de4babf65df/fbo.go

Comment: Amazing! I couldn't seem to figure out what exactly they wanted to point to there, but after looking at your FBO code its all a lot more clear to me know.